# Modify style of Recaptcha

Tags: css, recaptcha

Is it possible to modify the style of the new div `NO CAPTCHA RECAPTCHA` of google using `css`?

```
<div style="background-color:transparent; color:transparent; border:none" id="google" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mypublickey"></div>
```

because I tried with background color and border but it doesn't work. Am I doing it in the wrong way or it is not possible?